# Asp.Net Web Api Action Methods Process Time logging

Tags: asp.net, rest, logging

I want to logging time infos of every web api action methods.I want to know when action method is started and when it is finished so I can find elapsed time of an action.

I can logging every request and response with use custom handler(DelegatingHandler).Is it possible to log methods start and finish times use handler or something etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `IHttpModule` and handle required methods (for example `Application_EndRequest`)
2. You can derive `ActionFilterAttribute` and annotate your controllers

Start/finish time... `Stopwatch` should be accessible, or you can work with current DateTime.

Comment: Thanks ,using custom  ActionFilterAttribute and customizing OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted works